# Retrieving an entity from CRM 4.0 and i do not have guid for that

Tags: plugins, entity, crm

I am developing a plugin.  The plugin is supposed to do some stuff whenever an update of a contact occurs.  I am retrieving the whole contact object by using service.Retreive("contact",guid,cols).

Is there any way to access/retrieve other entities present in CRM? My requirement is, whenever there is an update event for contact, I want to update another entity present in the organization and I do not have guid of that entity.

you help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that I understood you correctly..

First, if you want to use fields of the entity for which you register an event you do not have to use the "Retrive" method. You can use images. On each step you can attach "Pre" & "Post" images. Image gets the properties of the primary entity before the core platform operation has occurred or after operation has been completed.

Of course you can gain access to other entities from your plugin(Even if you do not have GUID). For this purpose you can use Fetch or Query Expression.

More information [here(crm4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928429.aspx).
Hope this helps.